# How can I make a local variable in string interpolation inaccessible from outside?

Tags: ruby, local-variables, string-interpolation

In this code:

```
s = "#{a = 2; b = 3; a * b}" # =>"6"
a # => "2"
```

local variables `a` and `b` are created within a string interpolation, and can be reached outside of the string interpolation because string interpolation is not a block, despite the curly braces.

I would like to create local variables within string interpolation, which are needed only there and not elsewhere in the code, and which should be deleted after the string interpolation is done to minimize side effects and potential variable collisions.

I tried to make a code block to achieve the locality of the variables, but no success:

```
s = "#{{a = 2; b = 3; a * b}}"
```

Same with `do`...`end`.

```
s = "#{do a = 2; b = 3; a * b; end}"
```

Comment: String interpolation's curly braces--`{` preceded by a pound sign-- have nothing to do with a block. Matz could have as well defined it as follows: `n = 3; "#|n|"`.

Comment: You need a separate scope, such as the use of a method or proc. You could write, for example, `s = ->{ "#{a = 2; b = 3; a * b}" }.call #=> "6"; a #=> 
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'a' for main:Object`.

Comment: `s = "#{->() { a = 2; b = 3; a * b }.()}"`

Comment: ...or even something as moronic as this: `s = [99].reduce('') {  "#{a = 2; b = 3; a * b}" } #=> "6"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You might want to turn them into an answer.

Comment: Looks somewhat cryptic but works. These seems to be similar to JavaScript unnamed functions.

Comment: So the question at this point should be if something less cryptic like a named function/method may not be more beneficial to any future readers of the code, including yourself.

Comment: Actually, this question has nothing to do with string interpolation. The OP just wants a local variable to be trapped inside some construct.

Comment: The question should be: what are you trying to solve. I'm worried that you might interepolate user input this way? If so: don't. It is dangerous.

Comment: Yes, in fact user input, but I am the only user of that app. A command line program which generates a webpage from a JSON database, and accepts numerous CLI arguments, which gowern the fine details of the generated webpage. Maybe should I use some ERB approach?

Comment: @Konstantin _"Maybe should I use some ERB approach?"_ – your question is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/391826). Instead of asking about your actual problem (e.g. "how to pass arguments to CLI app?"), you're asking about your attempted solution (limiting variable scope in string interpolation).

Comment: No, I know how to pass variables by optparse library. But I realized that I sometimes create new variables between the string interpolation curly braces, because I believed that they become local variables and will be deleted after the string interpolation. Recently I realized that in fact it is not the case. Fortunately this practice didn't caused big problems in my programs till now, but I would like to avoid them in the future too. This is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 3):

Just out of curiosity. The following code won’t *drop* the local variables, but it effectively unsets their values, so calling `a` (or `b`) after this will return `nil`:

```
%Q|#{
  a = 2
  b = 3
  (a * b).tap do 
    binding.local_variable_set(:a, nil)
    binding.local_variable_set(:b, nil)
  end
}|
```

The approaches **below** will raise `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'a' ...` instead on accessing `a` after these statements:

```
"#{->() { a = 2; b = 3; a * b }.()}"

# or, credits to @engineersmnky
"#{->(a = 2, b = 3) { a * b }.()}"
"#{->(a, b) { a * b }.(2, 3)}"
```

Also:

```
"#{instance_eval { a = 2; b = 3; a * b }}"
```

Comment: a bit cleaner in my opinion would be `"#{->(a=2,b=3) {a * b}.()}"` or `"#{->(a,b) { a * b}.(2,3)}"`

Answer (score 1):

here is my try:

```
> s = "#{def yielder; yield; end; yielder do a=2; b=3; a*b; end;}"
#=> "6" 

> a
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
> b
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object
```

Blocks generally use the bindings that are in existence when the block is defined, except when an existing binding conflicts with a block variable and the block variable is used. Additional local bindings can be defined within a block and these will be lost when the block is finished executing.

Comment: The piped variables `|a,b|` are meaningless in this context since `yield` is just passing control to the block but not passing any arguments

Comment: @engineersmnky : yes you are right, let me remove unnecessary piped variables

Answer (score -1):

Also an approach with the new Ruby 2.5 yield_self featurette

```
"#{ 2.yield_self{|a| 3.yield_self{|b| a*b}} }"
```

Comment: This makes a little sense since if you know the values upfront (and if you don’t, the above is simply impossible,) you might do `"#{2 * 3}"` with the same effect.

Comment: Of course in a real program I would use variable names instead of literals to derive other values by computation. So if I have some other variables in my program called "c" and "d" I can write:
s="#{ c.yield_self{|a| e=1.0/a; d.yield_self{|b| a*e}} }"